# Make extension install after core modules

Tags: extensions, installation, dependency

I have an extension i created that modifies core attributes. I want to make sure it is installed after all magento core modules. Is there a way i can use the depends node in my app/etc/modules/*.xml file to set the extension to be installed last? or do i have to include every core module inside it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include in the `<depends>` node the modules that you actually modify.
I doubt you modify something in the tables of all modules.
If you modify a product or category attribute include `<Mage_Catalog />` if you modify a customer attribute include `<Mage_Customer />` if you modify an order column include `<Mage_Sales />`...you get the point.
The order you use for the depend modules is not important.